# How to build ExtJS app into .js file, not inside index.html?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I have Ext JS app (5.0, MVC) which need to be placed inside DIV container in HTML page. Everything works in development environment, but i can't understand how to use sencha cmd to build it, because build process generates "launcher" code and places it inside index.html
When i copy/paste builded JS code into my template - it works fine.

So, question is: can i somehow redirect build JS output into .js file, which i'll include (with <source>) in my HTML, so i'll do not need to copy/paste JS code everytime i rebuilded app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimenting found it myself:

app.json

`"output": {
    "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
    "microloader": {
        "path": "microloader.js",
        "embed": false,
        "enable": true
    }
},`

and
`<script src="microloader.js"></script>` in my template.

index.html still will be overwritten on every build, but doesn't matter for me.